# Codeigniter theme assets iniside theme folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im using [phil strugeon's template library](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template) on my current project. so far, I've read that

you can put all your asses with this kind of structure on your CI:

```
/application
  /themes
    /mytheme
      /views
        /layouts
/assets  <-----all css and JS are included here.
/system
```

but what Im expecting is is there a way that I could restructure it on this manner?

```
/application
  /themes
    /mytheme
      /assets  <-----all css, imgs and JS are included here.
      /views
        /layouts
/system
```

so that when I import the whole theme folder it would also include the css,imgs, and js with it?

Comment: It's better to have you css and js files in the home dir like that

Comment: Also, you need to change the path for calling the assets..1) change the path for css, js files inside your PHP view pages 2) change the path inside css files for loading images

Comment: @Wold uhm, in what way would it be better? I mean in Wordpress you can simply import all the theme assets and files by placing the data inside wp-contents/themes. I would like to have that kind of functionality also for more easier theme management. thanks

Comment: wait you are using wordpress embedded in codeigniter?

Comment: I think the point is that Wordpress puts all the files in the www folder, while codeigniter (correctly) encourages you to put your application folder above the root, resulting in a more secure file system. You still need to place the JS and CSS files on your root, for browser access. In my opinion that's why the author chose to put the assets folder outside of the application folder.